# specjvm2008 compliance of the benchmark

Tags: java, jvm

I am just running specjvm2008 by running the command
java -jar SPECjvm2008.jar -wt 5s -it 240s -bt 2 compress

I am getting the output as :
WARNING: Run will not be compliant.
Not a compliant sequence of benchmarks for publication.

Kit signature and checksum is validated.
This can take several minutes.
Use argument '-ikv' to skip this.
....................................passed.

I am not able to figure out why the warning which says not a compliant sequence of benchmarks for publication? Does it mean the jre I am using has not passed the benchmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, literally, the benchmark sequence containing only `compress` benchmark is not compliant for publication. You need to run all benchmark to publish the compliant result.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to choose the jdk version to run the specjvm2008 ?if I have more than 1 versions installed?

Comment: Um? Run it with different JDK, done. Where do you think "java" command is coming from?

Comment: I mean, is it all fine If I just specify the path of the jdk version 2 in the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: You have to make sure what "java" also runs the executable from $JAVA_HOME/bin/java.